# How can I import microsoft edge bookmarks on firefox?

Tags: firefox, microsoft, bookmarks

I recently turned to ubuntu and want to import those bookmarks to firefox. These bookmarks have been stored on cloud (microsoft account).

Answer (score 0):

By default, MS Edge should throw all it's crap here. From there you'd copy the links it saves and then import them into firefox. (I'm not sure if you can do pop them all into a text file or you have to do them one by one.)

```
C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC\MicrosoftEdge\User\Default\Favorites
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have formatted windows drive.

Comment: In that case, you're pretty much screwed (to put it lightly.) Your bookmarks aren't available through your MS account as of now, and you have to have Edge available to access them. Seeing as how you can't install Edge on other systems as it's native to Win10, there's not much you can do without Windows 10+Edge accessible. Sorry.